# "for i in True,False:" Python, explanation needed

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I hope I can ask here for an explanation not just a solution to problem.

So I know how this works:

```
for i in range(10):
 //blocks of code
```

It goes from i =0 all the way up to i = 9, so it the blocks of code executes 10 times. My question is what does this do:

```
for i in True,False:
 //block of code
```

Does this run just once ? Or two times ? Or does the blocks of code use the i as True/False or 1/0 ?

I hoe someone can clarify this for me. Thanks !

Comment: Why don't you try it in the interpreter and find out? `for i in True, False: print i` will tell you pretty promptly.

Comment: `True, False` is the same as `(True, False)` which is a 2-element tuple. What's strange about it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `True,False` is a tuple, equivalent to `(True, False)`. That tuple has a length of two, so the block of code runs twice.

As for whether it runs as booleans or integers, that depends on how you use `i`. `bool` is a subclass of `int` in Python, so it will normally act as a boolean, but you will be able to do mathematical operations with it as it is basically just another representation of an integer.

Answer (score 5):

In Python, the `for` keyword is really a "foreach".  It iterates over the objects you give to it.

`range()` returns a list (in Python 2.x), so `for i in range(3):` iterates over the integers in the list.  In Python 3.x `range()` returns an iterator, so `for i in range(3):` iterates over the integers yielded up by the iterator.  Either way, `i` is set to integers from the range, one at a time.

Python has tuples, which are usually written like this: `(True, False)`

That's a tuple with two elements.  The first is `True` and the second is `False`.

But in Python, you don't actually need the parentheses for a tuple; a series of values separated by commas is also a tuple.  Thus this is a tuple equivalent to the first one: `True, False`

It's tricky to make a length-1 tuple in Python.  You still need the comma, so it looks weird.  Here's a length-1 tuple: `0,`

This looks weird but it's legal: a loop that will run exactly once, because we pass a length-1 tuple to `for`:

```
for i in 0,:
    print i
```

This will print `0` and terminate.

Answer (score 2):

`for ... in ...` loops basically cycle through every element in what's called an iterable object. Iterable objects include lists, dicts, tuples, etc. `range(x)` returns the list `[0,1,2,3,...,(x-1)]`, for example, so

```
for i in range(10):
 //blocks of code
```

is really the same thing as

```
for i in [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]:
 //blocks of code
```

Hence, you can think of

```
for i in True,False:
 //block of code
```

as being interpreted as

```
for i in [True,False]:
 //block of code
```

Comment: No need to think of `True, False` as a list; it actually *is* a tuple.

Comment: I know, but I wanted to put it in terms of the first example I gave for simplicity. In this case, there is no difference between a tuple and a list.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: it runs two times.  The first time, `i==True`, and the second time, `i==False`.

You need to know how `for` loops work and what a `tuple` is for this to make sense.  A for loop just... well... *loops* over an iterable.  You could rewrite what you have a couple different ways:

```
# The parentheses here don't do anything different from what you had, actually.
# But it makes it more clear that you're making a tuple and iterating over it.
for i in (True, False):
    // block of code
```

Equivalently,  you can loop over a list:

```
for i in [True, False]:
    // block of code
```

You'll get exactly the same results this way, you're just looping through a list instead of a tuple.